# Pointers in linked lists

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm studying lists currently (trying to recreate them) and I came across a weird problem. Here's my struct:

```
struct listNode{
    listNode(int n, listNode* ne = NULL){
        value = n;
        next = ne;
    }
    int value;
    listNode* next;
};
listNode* head = NULL;
```

Now I made a function to add an element to the bottom:

```
void add(int n){
    if(head == NULL){
        head = new listNode(n);
        return;
    }
    listNode* n1 = head;
    while(n1 != NULL){ //Should be: while(n1->next != NULL){
        n1 = n1->next;
    }
    n1 = new listNode(n); //Should be: n1->next = new listNode(n);
}
```

But this isn't adding any element past the head. Now, I already figured out the solution (see comments above) my problem is that I do not understand why my first function didn't work.
I'll explain what I understood with a scheme:

**The Beginning**
HEAD = NULL;

**I add 1**
HEAD = [1, NULL];

**I add 2**
*The while loop arrives at the last element (where "next" is NULL) and creates in it the new element*
HEAD = [1, new listNode(2)];
*Result*
HEAD = [1, POINTER] [2, NULL];

Now, why `n1` after the while loop isn't what I wan't it to be?

Comment: Never title a question "How pointers work?". The title should be something related to LinkedLists

Comment: @asimes Didn't know really what to write, sorry. Anyway, silent downvoters, care to explain?

Comment: Let's say you have `int n = 5; int m = n; m = 7`. Do you expect `n` should become 7? Don't think so. But nevertheless you say `n1 = n1->next; n1 = new listNode(n);` and expect the `next` member of previous `n1` to change. Weird, huh?

Comment: @n.m. If after `n1 = n1->next;` `n1` is null I want it to point to the new element

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "c++ linked list insertion" for some examples.  Compare those with yours.

Comment: You want *what* to point to the new element?

Comment: @n.m. The attribute "next" of the last element

Comment: Then you should assign the new element to the attribute `next` of the last element. Before saying "but *n1* **is** the attribute `next` of the last element", look again at `m = n; m = 7`. Are you assigning 7 to `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does not work becuase `n1` is a local variable of the function. Any changes of the variable do not influence on other nodes of the list.

You should change the original nodes of the list. The function can be written the following way

```
void add( int value )
{
    listNode **node = &head;

    while ( *node ) node = &( *node )->next;

    *node = new listNode( value );
}
```

In this case because variable `node` points to the actual fields of the list it indeed changes them.

Comment: I understood, so I was just making a copy of the "next" attribute, and by editing the copy the original does not get affected, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of it this way: no matter what you used to do within the `while` loop, the condition of the while loop was such that the loop would only terminate once `n1` became `null`.  So, the value of `n1` was guaranteed to be `null` after the loop.

However, the value of `n1` after the while loop was irrelevant, because you were not using it after the while loop.

On the other hand, your last instruction was `n1 = new listNode(n);` so you were creating a new listNode, and assigning it to `n1`, which you were then forever forgetting by leaving the function.  (So, the new node was being leaked.)

Comment: Spot on, minus the *"garbage-collected soon afterwards"*. This is C++, it was being leaked.

Comment: But if the last value was null why by changing it (since it was got by n1->next) it does not affect head's next?

Answer (score 1):

Is is simple,

```
while(n1 != NULL){
    n1 = n1->next;
}

// n1 here is null
// head here is [1, NULL]

n1 = new listNode(n);

// n1 here is something
// head here is [1, NULL]
```

so unless you set the previous element's next pointer of the head to your new element, it won't work

Comment: Then where is this stored if `n1` isn't head's next?

Comment: The n1 is lost forever, you do not assign it to something recoverable, it becomes a memory leak

Comment: But isn't n1 the attribute "next" of the last element?

Comment: no, as soon as you say `n1 = n1->next` n1 is null, and no longer equal to the head

Comment: `n1 = n1->next` is going to be valid during all the while loop, except in the end, where the last element is pointing to null, do you understand now?

Comment: I understood my big mistake, thanks. I guess it's the fault of too much coding... ;)